# Intents - startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I make app with the MainActivity and Activity2. I have sent info from MainActivity to Activity2 and Activity2 to MainActivity.

I would like to sent the variable opcio to startActivityForResult but I do not know how. I use this code from MainActivity:

```
opcio = OPCIO_1;
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class), ACTIVITY_NUM);
```

After from Activity2 I do not know to recovery this info.

Please Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something along these lines?

Send extra from MainActivity to Activity2:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("extra", opcio);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Retrieve extra in Activity2:

```
String opcio = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra");
```

Sending extra from Activity2 to MainActivity:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("extra", opcio);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
```

Retrieve extra in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        String opcio = data.getStringExtra("extra);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
opcio = OPCIO_1;
i.putExtra("send", opcio);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

Activity2 where closes:

```
setResult(1);
finish();
```

MainActivity :

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 1){
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. The little problem is that from the activity2 also I have that send information. Then, Have I create a new Intent? How do you link all information of the two intents?